# factory method pattern in C#

Tags: c#, factory-method

`class A` implements `IC`
`class B` implements `IC`

`class Factory` has a method `GetObject(int x)`; `x=0` for `A`, `x=1` for `B`.

How can I force the usage of `Factory.GetObject` method to create objects of type `A` and `B` and prevent something like `new A()`, which should be `Factory.GetObject(0)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I force the usage of Factory GetObject method to create objects of type A and B and prevent something like new A()

You can't force the usage of `Factory.GetObject`, this is something that you should write in the documentation of the API you are providing after marking A and B constructors internal.

```
public class A: IC
{
    internal A() { }
}

public class B: IC
{
    internal B() { }
}

public static class Factory
{
    public static IC GetObject(int x)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            return new A();
        }

        if (x == 1)
        {
            return new B();
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("x must be 1 or 2", "x");
    }
}
```

This way those constructors will not be accessible from other assemblies. Also don't forget about Reflection which will allow for direct instantiation of those classes no matter how hard you try to hide them.

Comment: why don't we make class A & B `internal` as well?

Comment: @Genzer: Because you're not able to return an internal type from a public method?

Comment: @Tanzelax, why not? In the `GetObject` method signature we are using the `IC` interface which needs to be public but `A` and `B` could be internal without any problem.

Comment: Huh, my mistake; for some reason I thought you couldn't do that even if you're returning it as the public interface... not sure why I thought that.

Comment: one other thought...you could, as a matter of convention, put the factory and instances classes in an assembly by themselves, so that any calls to the instances are always (or as often as possible) from a another assembly.  Not foolproof, but would serve as a standing reminder that the factory is to be used for instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant (it's been a year...) but here's how you can achieve further enforcement of the factory usage:

```
public class A
{
   internal protected A() {}
}

public class AFactory
{
   public A CreateA()
   {
      return new InternalA();
   }

   private class InternalA : A
   {
      public InternalA(): base() {}
   }
}
```

Components using class A cannot directly create it (so long they don't inherit it...).